# Best memory management routine

Tags: iphone, xcode, dealloc

I am writing an iPhone application, and now it is time to start cleaning up memory.

By a better programmer than myself, i was told that each time I perform a alloc, that I should dealloc the memory at the end of the module.

Is this statement that each time there is a alloc, that there should be a removal in the dealloc section of the .m file??

thanks
tony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to read up on the memory management guides on the Apple developer site.  Basically you need to have a `release` or `autorelease` for every `new, copy, or alloc` you use.  But the release ideally should be in the function that called `new, copy, or alloc`, not in your dealloc function.  dealloc should only be used for releasing objects that were retained in the @property section of your header file.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than just listen to what your colleague has told you - Have a read of the [Memory Management Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html).

Memory management isn't something you do at the end as 'cleaning up' it's something you need to think about when programming. Don't just rely on what somebody tells you is a rule of thumb. Read the documents, understand them, and then use the rules of thumb to help you remember what they are.

For example - When you create a local variable in a method with `alloc`, you can't wait until the dealloc to `release` it, because by then that variable has gone out of scope, you don't have an object to call `release` on' and you have a leak. So that *rule of thumb* isn't any good.